# rvm, ruby command not found in Rye gem

Tags: shell, rvm

I'm using ruby 1.8 and have gem https://github.com/delano/rye installed that need to remote ssh to amazon.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rye'

instance = Rye::Box.new('amazone_ip', :user => "ubuntu", :safe => false, :keys => "amazone_key")
```

I got errors by running those commands:

```
instance.execute 'rvm list' #bash: rvm: command not found
instance.execute 'ruby -v' #bash: ruby: command not found
```

It's ok if I run the command instance.execute `ls -la`.
I would think there is problem with `$PATH` load, that I have checked it

```
instance.execute 'echo $PATH'
#[/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games, , 0, ]

#But it's in server:
$echo $PATH
#/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll wager you don't have rvm loading because its either not loading your local .bashrc or you don't have the RVM loading line (sourcing line) in your .bashrc, its in your .bash_profile. Just move the RVM line to your .bashrc and then source the .bashrc at the end of your .bash_profile.

If its calling bash in sh-compatible mode, then you can set BASH_ENV in your .profile and point it at your .bashrc which will then load RVM that way.

Comment: rvm loads in my local .bashrc, but it doesn't load rvm command on the server while connecting by using rye. Can you give me more details about solution?

Comment: That I'm afraid I can't. I have never used rye.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
instance.execute('source ~/.bash_profile && rvm list')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else finds it useful as this is an old question -

For a non-login shell the user's paths and environment variables are not loaded.

I needed to add this in my `.bashrc` file right at the very top.

`[[ -s "/home/douser/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/home/douser/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`